# Counting occurrences of a string in an array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, string, object, find-occurrences

I have a code...

```
var userArray=userIn.match(/(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|\d+|[()])/g);
```

...that separates the user input of a chemical formula into its components.

For example, entering `Cu(NO3)2N3` will yield

> Cu , ( , N , O , 3 , ) , 2 , N , 3.

In finding the percentage of each element in the entire weight, I need to count how many times each element is entered.

So in the example above,

```
Cu : 1 , 
N  : 5 , 
O : 6
```

Any suggestions of how I should go about doing this?

Comment: Does the quantifier _always_ come right after the element? Also, is nesting allowed? Are two digit numbers allowed?

Comment: This is much more than just counting occurrences. This is parsing and multiplying.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, this requires an actual parser - not a particularly hard one though. Tokens are letters, numbers (quantifiers) and brackets. I don't mind giving the OP a good answer on _how_ to implement it but it's not very clear yet.

Comment: Yes, the quantifier will be right after the element, and two digits numbers ARE allowed.  So entering H12, will be H, 12 .  The only exception would be with parenthesis, where the following number would have to multiply by everything inside the parenthesis.

Comment: @TGH The `g` modifier makes it return all occurrences in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You need to build a parser

There is no simple way around that. You need nesting and memory, a regular expression can't handle that very well (well, a *real* CS regulular expression can't handle that at all).

First, you get the result regexp you have.  This is called [**Tokenization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization).

Now, you have to actually **parse** that.

I suggest the following approach I will give you pseudo code because I think it will be better deductively. If you have any questions about it let me know:

> method *chemistryExpression*(**tokens**):    #Tokens is the result of your regex
>
> 1. Create an empty map called **map**
> 2. While the next token is a **letter**, consume it (remove it from the tokens)
>
>    2.1 Add the letter to the map with occurrence 1 or increment it by one if it's already inside the map
> 3. If the next token is `(`, consume it:   # Deal with nesting
>
>    3.1  Add the occurrences from *parseExpression*(tokens) to the map (note, tokens changed)
>
>    3.2 Remove the  extra `)` you've just encountered
> 4. **num** = consume tokens while the next token is a number and convert to int
> 5. Multiply the occurances of all tokens in the map by **num**
> 6. Return the map

#### Implementation suggestion

- The map can just be an object.

  - Adding to the map is checking if the key is there, if it is not, set it to 1, if it is there, increment its value by one.
  - Multiplying can be done using a `for... in` loop.
- This solution is *recursive* this means you're using a function which calls itself (chemistryExpression) in this case. This parser is a very basic example of a recursive descent parser and handles nesting well.
- Common sense and good practice necessitate two methods

  - peek - what is the next token in the tokens, this is `tokens[0]`
  - next - grab the next token from tokens, this is `tokens.unshift()`

Comment: Thanks!  I think I understand for the most part, so I'll get to work!

Answer (score 0):

For each value in userArray, check if there is a next element anf if that next element is a number, if so, add this number to the count of the current element type, else add 1. You can use an object as a map to store a count for each distinct element type :

```
var map = { }
map[userArray[/*an element*/] = ...
```

EDIT : if you have numbers longer than a digit, then in a loop while the next is a number, concatenate all numbers into a string and parseInt()